# Make dispatcher example to work

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a working program from this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx . I think I'm almost done, but I can't who shold be calling the
 Dispatcher : what should i use instead of tomorrow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ? I think I should put the UI thread, but how can i do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestDelegate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void NoArgDelegate();
        private delegate void OneArgDelegate(String arg);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the status image and start the rotation animation.
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = "Contacting Server";

            // Start fetching the weather forecast asynchronously.
            NoArgDelegate fetcher = new NoArgDelegate(
                this.FetchWeatherFromServer);
            fetcher.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }


        private void FetchWeatherFromServer()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000);        


            // Schedule the update function in the UI thread.
            tomorrow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal,
                new OneArgDelegate(UpdateUserInterface), 
                weather);
        }

        private void UpdateUserInterface(String weather)
        {    
            //Update UI text
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = "Fetch Forecast";  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the referencing, `Dispatcher` as introduced in .NET framework 3 and up
is located in the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace and not in `System.Threading` .

The `System.Windows` namespace is available in WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) projects.

Comment: same problem: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Dispatcher' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I've found the solution: I'm developping a Windows Form Application, but Dispatcher in only avaible for Windows Presentation Foundation.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Forms you can just use `this.BeginInvoke(...)`.

It is a method of `Control` class, and `Form` derives from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`?

Comment: I've already tried it, and i get the following error : "Error 1 'TestDelegate.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'TestDelegate.Form1' could be found "

Comment: Ahh, I get it. STupid me. You're using a WPF structure, but your window is a `Form`, i.e. WinForms. In that case, there's no Dispatcher - instead, you do an `Invoke()`.