# Keeping a WPF UI responsive while showing a slow loading UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

We have a WPF application written using the MVVM pattern. Within the application is a TabControl with different UserControls within each tab. Under certain conditions one of the UserControls on a tab can take a significant portion of time to load when switching to the containing tab.

This is NOT because of any performance bottlenecks in the ViewModel. But instead, is due to significant amount of time that the usercontrol takes to bind to the ViewModel, and to create the various UI elements contained within it and initialize them.

When the user clicks on the tab for this usercontrol, the UI becomes completely unresponsive until the control has completed loading. If fact you don't even see the "active tab" switch until everything is loaded.

What strategies could I use to display a "spinner" with some sort of "please wait, loading..." message while waiting for the UI elements to complete loading?

UPDATE with sample code:

The below demonstrates the type of problem I am trying to get around. When you click on the "slow tab". The UI becomes unresponsive until all the items in the slow tab have rendered.

In the below, TestVM is the viewmodel for the slow tab. It has a large collection of children objects. Each created with it's own data template.

How could I display a "loading" message while the slow tab finishes loading?

```
public class MainVM
{
    private TestVM _testVM = new TestVM();
    public TestVM TestVM
    {
        get { return _testVM; }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// TestVM is the ViewModel for the 'slow tab'. It contains a large collection of children objects that each will use a datatemplate to render. 
/// </summary>
public class TestVM
{
    private IEnumerable<ChildBase> _children;

    public TestVM()
    {
        List<ChildBase> list = new List<ChildBase>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                list.Add(new Child1());
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 1)
            {
                list.Add(new Child2());
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(new Child3());
            }
        }
        _children = list;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ChildBase> Children
    {
        get {  return _children; }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Just a base class for a randomly positioned VM
/// </summary>
public abstract class ChildBase
{
    private static Random _rand = new Random(1);

    private int _top = _rand.Next(800);
    private int _left = _rand.Next(800);

    public int Top { get { return _top; } }
    public int Left { get { return _left; } }
}

public class Child1 : ChildBase { }

public class Child2 : ChildBase  { }

public class Child3 : ChildBase { }

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- Template for the slow loading tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestVM}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"></Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- examples of different child templates contained in the slow rendering tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child1}">
            <DataGrid></DataGrid><!--simply an example of a complex control-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child2}">
            <RichTextBox Width="30" Height="30">
                <!--simply an example of a complex control-->
            </RichTextBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child3}">
            <Calendar Height="10" Width="15"></Calendar>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Fast Loading tab">
                <TextBlock Text="Not Much Here"></TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Slow Tab">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding TestVM}"></ContentControl>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Use Task<T> and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), will this do?

Comment: If I hear the words `TabControl`, `Binding` and **slow tabs** in the same sentence, it reminds me of the fact that TabControls have an issue with the way it tries to optimize itself when you bind it to an ItemsSource. Usually you can resolve the speed issue by fixing the template. If you are interested, try to test with a custom template that doesn't allow the TabControl to do that optimization. I will post a link or two...

Comment: [Keeping the WPF Tab Control from destroying its children](http://web.archive.org/web/20101007170247/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What do u need is here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        // Delegates to be used in placking jobs onto the Dispatcher. 
        private delegate void NoArgDelegate();
        private delegate void OneArgDelegate(String arg);

        // Storyboards for the animations. 
        private Storyboard showClockFaceStoryboard;
        private Storyboard hideClockFaceStoryboard;
        private Storyboard showWeatherImageStoryboard;
        private Storyboard hideWeatherImageStoryboard;

        public Window1(): base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }  

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Load the storyboard resources.
            showClockFaceStoryboard = 
                (Storyboard)this.Resources["ShowClockFaceStoryboard"];
            hideClockFaceStoryboard = 
                (Storyboard)this.Resources["HideClockFaceStoryboard"];
            showWeatherImageStoryboard = 
                (Storyboard)this.Resources["ShowWeatherImageStoryboard"];
            hideWeatherImageStoryboard = 
                (Storyboard)this.Resources["HideWeatherImageStoryboard"];   
        }

        private void ForecastButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the status image and start the rotation animation.
            fetchButton.IsEnabled = false;
            fetchButton.Content = "Contacting Server";
            weatherText.Text = "";
            hideWeatherImageStoryboard.Begin(this);

            // Start fetching the weather forecast asynchronously.
            NoArgDelegate fetcher = new NoArgDelegate(
                this.FetchWeatherFromServer);

            fetcher.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        private void FetchWeatherFromServer()
        {
            // Simulate the delay from network access.
            Thread.Sleep(4000);              

            // Tried and true method for weather forecasting - random numbers.
            Random rand = new Random();
            String weather;

            if (rand.Next(2) == 0)
            {
                weather = "rainy";
            }
            else
            {
                weather = "sunny";
            }

            // Schedule the update function in the UI thread.
            tomorrowsWeather.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new OneArgDelegate(UpdateUserInterface), 
                weather);
        }

        private void UpdateUserInterface(String weather)
        {    
            //Set the weather image 
            if (weather == "sunny")
            {       
                weatherIndicatorImage.Source = (ImageSource)this.Resources[
                    "SunnyImageSource"];
            }
            else if (weather == "rainy")
            {
                weatherIndicatorImage.Source = (ImageSource)this.Resources[
                    "RainingImageSource"];
            }

            //Stop clock animation
            showClockFaceStoryboard.Stop(this);
            hideClockFaceStoryboard.Begin(this);

            //Update UI text
            fetchButton.IsEnabled = true;
            fetchButton.Content = "Fetch Forecast";
            weatherText.Text = weather;     
        }

        private void HideClockFaceStoryboard_Completed(object sender,
            EventArgs args)
        {         
            showWeatherImageStoryboard.Begin(this);
        }

        private void HideWeatherImageStoryboard_Completed(object sender,
            EventArgs args)
        {           
            showClockFaceStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
        }        
    }
```

P.S. Perhaps it is useful as well http://tech.pro/tutorial/662/csharp-tutorial-anonymous-delegates-and-scoping and [Make dispatcher example to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583833/make-dispatcher-example-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

Make your control lazy-load its contents.

To do that expose an ObservableCollection property in your TestVM class and attach event handlers to CollectionChanged (possible PropertyChanged too) to add actual UI elements.

In Window1 prepare the data to load in TestVM on a separate thread (are you doing any web queries?), pass the data to TestVM on the UI thread.

If TestVM child controls themselves load slowly you can split that drive that process from a separate thread too but that's (way) more difficult to pull of, so hopefully it's the data loading that's the slow part

Comment: Thanks for the idea Sten, but what I was trying to demonstrate was that all of the VMs have been created and have their data fully initialized before you click on the tab. It's the creation of all the UI elements themselves (vs the ViewModels) that is the performance hit and that is what I'm trying to speed up.

Comment: @eoldre ok, so you do have the more complex problem. Speeding up the UI and making it responsive are not necessarily the same thing. UI controls *have to* be processed on the UI thread and even if you initiate the process from another thread the UI will still lock up. Speeding things up is up to you but generally avoid constructor loading, make things lazy-load, child controls included. One (clumsy) option is to space the loading of child elements and initiate it from a separate thread with a bit of sleep between each, so they appear sequentially, as if animated, your UI will be mostly free

Answer (score 0):

Causes could be Slow Code in a Binding Converter, Coerce Value Callback, Properties could all make a binding appear slow. For Example, Consider An Image whose source binds to a URL. This could load slow due to network lags.

Also avoid switching to dispatcher context - unless really needed. For example to launch threads, Waiting for WaitHandles, even large/slow synchronous I/O operations etc etc

Sten Petrov's suggestion to lazy load (UI and Data Virtualization) is vital too.